# interpret sentiment analysis result (naive baye, svm , maxent)

Tags: r, svm, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes, text-analysis

i have done the sentiment analysis for some airline reviews using code from https://datascienceplus.com/sentiment-analysis-with-machine-learning-in-r/ ... but i am facing a problem of interpreting the results of naive Bayes, SVM and the others . so my question is how do i interpret these results? (how do i make statistical sense out of it for my final year research for B.sc Statistics? ) Thank You!

Comment: this is post would be better suited on CrossValidated or the datascience stackexchange

Comment: owk thanks, i will post it there now